# Disk cloning software for OFFLINE drives?

Tags: windows, hard-disk, disk-image

I'm looking for a disk cloning program that does NOT run from a Windows shadow volume or something that enables it to run whilst the disk is currently in use.  It should run by rebooting the machine to run offline, but also NOT from a CDROM (my new machine doesn't have optical media).

Are there any options for this anymore?

Comment: I understand the "no optical drive" in the laptop, but do you have any problem with using a bootable USB containing a program such as Clonezilla?

Answer (score 1):

Clonezilla and DRBL both have a server mode you can run on another computer of some kind.

Even if its a raspberry pi 4 4gb or 8gb of RAM, and and external USB 3 storage.  SSD for ultimate speed.

Then you can PXE boot (pronounced pixie boot) your computer usually by pressing F11 or F12 a number of times on boot up.

Different computers may use different keys and you may have to go into your BIOS and enable this feature.